# Python: Import Source Code into Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've recently started using `eclipse` for my class over `IDLE`. So far I have no problems writing new code and creating new projects in eclipse.

However, when I open older code that was not originally written in my current project, eclipse seems to only open it as a text file.

For example, when I want to run a piece of code, I get a popup asking for an ANT build instead of running it using `pydev`. Also the code will not show up in the `pydev package explorer`.

How do I go about importing the `source code` into my project so `eclipse` will treat it as such.

Answer (score 5):

File > Import > "General" Folder > "File System" Folder > "Browse" button